# Why does Array.prototype.fill() have such a large performance difference compared to a `for` loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, v8

In doing a little testing (Chrome on macOS) of the `Array.prototype.fill()` method, its clearly almost twice as slow (if not slower) than simply creating your own `for` loop and filling your array.

Clearly doing something like:

```
for( var i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
   A[i] = 0;
}
```

vs

```
Array.fill(0);
```

The `Array.fill()` method would take ~210-250ms to fill an array of size 10000000, while the `for` loop would take ~70-90ms. It just seems that the `Array.fill()` method could be re-written to simply use a straight forward loop since you'd always know your initial index and target index.

```js
let arrayTest = new Array(10000000),
    startTime,
    endTime;

startTime = performance.now();
arrayTest.fill(0);
endTime = performance.now();

console.log("%sms", endTime - startTime);
arrayTest = new Array(10000000);
startTime = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++){
  arrayTest[i] = 0;
}
endTime = performance.now();

console.log("%sms", endTime - startTime);
```

The above actually shows an even greater discrepancy compared to when I tested locally.

Edit: I realize now after further testing that the discrepancies are diminished a lot when switching over to Firefox and its really engine dependent. I am guessing this is mainly a result of how different JavaScript engines are optimizing loops vs a method. It still seems as though a loop within the `Array.prototype.fill()` could be optimized to resolve this difference though.

Comment: Show us how you're testing this.

Comment: How were you testing this? How did you measure how long it took? What browser did you use? Are you using any polyfills?

Comment: I'd say this is more likley to vary from browser to browser

Comment: `Array.length` does not do what you think it does - unless you somehow created an array instance variable named `Array` that clashes with the `Array` constructor function - that might cause issues right there.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify how I was approaching this, thanks for the comments for clarifying.

Comment: @mootrichard `Date.now()` is not a high-precision timer suitable for benchmarking.

Comment: I realize its not a high precision measurement, but the discrepancy is still really large when comparing the two there (and I'm just writing it that way to run in the browser).

Comment: Date is not accurate.... look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now. One pass is not going to tell you anything and  better yet, look at jsperf

Comment: A possible explanation is that `Array.fill` is a more robust function than a simple loop. For example, it allows you to specify the start and end indices, and you can even pass in strings for those indices and they'll be converted automatically. Eg: `Array(1000000).fill(0, "100", "100000")` works. Presumably the checks involved to make that work cost us some performance over a vanilla loop.

Comment: Test I ran showed fill was faster by a slight margin that it made no difference with chrome on OSX.  Plus you reusing variables in your test and some other things that might lead to different results.

Comment: @epascarello I've updated the snippet to use the `performance` API for more precision. I agree that its likely more robust, but its still seems like in the end, its just having a start index, an end index, and looping through to fill the array.

@CRice I've run this locally using just Node.js and had extremely similar results. I have run it as many times as I could and tried restructuring initializing variables differently, but I still don't think those could account for such a huge gap in runtimes.

Comment: maybe a clue :http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.fill

Comment: the for loop in FFDE is 133x slower on my machine...

Comment: I rephrased the questions to just ask why there is such a huge performance difference between the two now, since it seems to be very JS engine dependent. It would still be great to get a solid answer around this, so anyone else trying to use this method could know what the tradeoffs could be.

Comment: Just for reference, I see similar behaviour with Array.from. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560099/is-it-worth-idiomatic-programming-an-es6-example. I used `performance` API for measurements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is consistent with reports that parts of Chrome are written in JavaScript, and rely on run time profiling and optimization to improve performance.

I packaged the test code in a function to be called repeatedly from a test page which can be loaded into different browsers (this is not a runnable snippet):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Array.prototype.fill</title>
<script>

Array.prototype.customFill = function( value, start = 0, end = this.length) {
    var count = end-start;
    if( count > 0 && count === Math.floor(count)){
        while( count--)
            this[start++]=value;
    }
    return this;
}

function test() {  
    let arrayTest,
        startTime,
        endTime,
        arraySize = 1000000;

    arrayTest = new Array(arraySize);
    startTime = performance.now();
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++){
      arrayTest[i] = 0;
    }
    endTime = performance.now();
    console.log("%sms (loop)", endTime - startTime);

    arrayTest = new Array(arraySize);
    startTime = performance.now();
    arrayTest.fill(0);
    endTime = performance.now();
    console.log("%sms (fill)", endTime - startTime);

    arrayTest = new Array(arraySize);
    startTime = performance.now();
    arrayTest.customFill(0);
    endTime = performance.now();
    console.log("%sms (custom fill)", endTime - startTime);   
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    open the console and click <button type="button" onclick="test()">test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The array size can be adjusted to suit the performance of the device used.

The results for Chrome under Windows showed a large performance win for the loop, *for the first two test clicks on test*. On the second click, timing for the loop seemed to improve. On the third click both loop and fill methods appeared to be optimized and ran with nearly equal, and improved, speed. Results were repeatable after reloading the page.

I find this consistent with Chrome script optimization strategies and inconsistent with Chrome's `Array.prototype.fill` being written in C++ or similar. Although  `Array.prototype.fill.toString()` reports the function body as "native code" is doesn't say what language it is written in.

---

*Update*

Added timings for a custom fill method, written for speed, and stored as `Array.prototype.customFill`.

Timings for Firefox are consistent with `Array.prototype.fill` being written in script. The native implementation outperformed the loop and was generally (but not always) faster than the custom fill method.

Timings for Chrome show are also consistent with `Array.prototype.fill` being written in some kind of script that becomes optimized. All three fill methods tested shown an increase in speed after one or two test clicks.

However, the custom fill method starts out over ten times faster than Chromes native version. You would need to put nonsense code in the custom method to slow it down enough to approach the native method's initial speed. Conversely, after optimization, the native method is around twice as fast - the custom method written in JavaScript never gets optimized to the same extent.

While Chromes `Array.prototype.fill` method could be written in JavaScript, additional explanation seems to be needed to account for the initial slowness and final performance optimizations noted.

Comment: So I tinkered with your example here in several different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari). The results were fairly interesting, although I adjusted your example to be initializing the array before each test, for consistency. The results are fairly interesting. Safari had the loop take _way_ longer than the fill() method for individual clicks. Firefox consistently had the `fill()` slightly edge out `loop`. Chrome definitely optimized by the third call and performance was nearly the same for both.

Comment: Good point about initializing the array each time. For interest I've updated the answer with timings for a custom fill method. Comparison of timings in Chrome shows there is still a lot of explaining to do :-(

Comment: I'm inclined to believe this is more due to V8's JIT marking the method as a hot object and then using that optimized version of it by the 3rd call. It would make sense and sort of explain the initial performance being so bad. It would still be _nice_ if the `fill()` method were just faster initially anyways, since it seems bad that custom written code performance better than a native method to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: if this is about JIT, then why would the performance of `fill()` improve on third or more run?  it's only called 3 times which seems not "hot" enough.

Comment: @Sajuuk - conjecture on whether the unoptimized method is written in Java, C#, Python, JavaScript or something else is just that - conjecture. I suspect it's not  JavaScript based on timings alone.

Answer (score 3):

This [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/fill-vs-for/1) confirms that fill is slower than a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

When array size is `1e5`, `fill` always wins.
When array size is `1e7`, `for` wins

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit (Jan 12, 2024):

As commented by @chester-fung, the above test cases are not configured properly. So below are the corrected test cases - which results in for loop almost always being better.

- [Array fill vs for 1e5](https://jsperf.app/hojesi/26)
- [Array fill vs for 1e7](https://jsperf.app/hojesi/25)

---

I've tested this in [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/) & [jsperf.app](https://jsperf.app/) - since  [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/) isn't discontinued.

Both the websites show that `Array.fill` is the fastest method.

Reference links:

- [Array fill vs for 1e5](https://jsperf.app/hojesi/3)
- [Array fill vs for 1e7](https://jsperf.app/hojesi/4)

Comment: Your test for "for loop" does not provide the fixed initial size for the array. This makes your comparison wrong. For loop is faster. https://na.cx/i/TPf5CQu.png

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Chester-fung. Does this mean that in my codebase the performance would vary depending on how I initialize the array? I mean `const A = []` vs `const A = Array(1e7)`

Comment: Yes. This is always important in every programming language. Browser will automatically set and expand when needed. for the testing case, i guess there will be serval times to expand the array. for example, initial size will be 100, then expand to 800, then expand to 16000, etc. These operations take time to do. However, this is just micro optimization. In daily use, you don't need to take care of it.