# How to add same elements to javascript array n times

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var fruits = [];
fruits.push("lemon", "lemon", "lemon", "lemon");
```

Instead of pushing same elements how can write it once like this:

```
fruits.push("lemon" * 4 times)
```

Comment: They're not the same elements. The first one has uppercase `L`, the others have lowercase `l`.

Comment: changed the typo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an array with same element repeated multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503146/create-an-array-with-same-element-repeated-multiple-times)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For primitives, use `.fill`:

```js
var fruits = new Array(4).fill('Lemon');
console.log(fruits);
```

For non-primitives, don't use `fill`, because then all elements in the array will reference the same object in memory, so mutations to one item in the array will affect every item in the array.

```js
const fruits = new Array(4).fill({ Lemon: 'Lemon' });

fruits[0].Apple = 'Apple';
console.log(JSON.stringify(fruits));


// The above doesn't work for the same reason that the below doesn't work:
// there's only a single object in memory

const obj = { Lemon: 'Lemon' };

const fruits2 = [];
fruits2.push(obj);
fruits2.push(obj);
fruits2.push(obj);
fruits2.push(obj);

fruits2[0].Apple = 'Apple';
console.log(JSON.stringify(fruits2));
```

Instead, explicitly create the object on each iteration, which can be done with `Array.from`:

```js
var fruits = Array.from(
  { length: 4 },
  () => ({ Lemon: 'Lemon' })
);
console.log(fruits);
```

For an example of how to create a 2D array this way:

```js
var fruits = Array.from(
  { length: 2 }, // outer array length
  () => Array.from(
    { length: 3 }, // inner array length
    () => ({ Lemon: 'Lemon' })
  )
);
console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Apparently here's *["Why never use new Array in Javascript"](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript)*

Comment: Sure, don't use it *wrong*. There are lots of ways to use lots of things wrong, unfortunately, and neither `new Array` nor `Array.from` are exceptions. `new Array` is fine as long as you fill the array afterwards.

Comment: check out this [question in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76340086/6908282) which shows that `Array.fill` is better in performance compared to for loop

Answer (score 3):

Try using Array constructor:

```
let myArray = Array(times).fill(elemnt)
```

See more here  [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)

Comment: You don't need `new` for arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> [You shouldn't use the array constructor,](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript) **use `[]` instead.**

```js
const myArray = [];   // declare array

myArray.length = 5; // set array size
myArray.fill('foo'); // fill array with any value

console.log(myArray); // log it to the console
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   const item = 'lemon'
   const arr = Array.from({length: 10}, () => item)
```

```js
const item = 'lemon'
const arr = Array.from({length: 10}, () => item)
console.log('arr', arr)
```