# Minify the declaration of array variables

Tags: javascript

I've to declare some variables and want to minify the code. Here is my current code:

```
let a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
let c = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Is there a way to minify the code?

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
  let a = b = c = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

or

```
  let a, b, c = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

or

```
  let a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  let b = a; // b becomes a pointer to "a"
  let c = a;
```

Comment: `let a = [0,0,0,0], b = [...a], c = [...a]`

Comment: or you could do something [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831998/how-to-add-same-elements-to-javascript-array-n-times/51832006#51832006) `const [a, b, c] = Array.from({ length: 3 }, () => new Array(10).fill(0))`, though it seems a bit odd to have those multiple independant variables, maybe consider a larger array or an object which contains `a`, `b`, and `c`

Comment: Thank you adiga for your solution.  IMHO "marked as duplicate" is wrong, even if I found the solution also somewhere on recommended page: the solutions are similar, but the questions are total different ;-)