# What idiomatic means in software design?

Tags: software-design

I'm always reading *fast, fun and idiomatic framework*. *opinated, idiomatic framework*, *with idiomatic syntax*. What does idiomatic means in software design and how to write, think and design idiomatic software and code? Or even what principles to keep in mind while writing (or trying) idiomatic code?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84102/what-is-idiomatic-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatic programming is programming using code that is natural to that language, much like idioms in natural language.

An example would be using arrow functions in ES6.

[Is it worth idiomatic programming? An ES6 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560099/is-it-worth-idiomatic-programming-an-es6-example)

I think you need to know the language well before you can code in an idiomatic way.